# Ask update and delete multiple array in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I have a real case in my project:

```
> db.foo.insert({a:'1',
... province: [{id:'1',name:'Yogyakarta',state:[{id:'1',name:'bantul'}]}]
... })
```

Then I find()...

```
> db.foo.find();
> { "_id" : ObjectId("5279ef4c6cfd9d5c0e19bbe0"),
    "a" : "1",
    "province" : [ 
    {"id" : "1",
         "name" : "Yogyakarta",
         "state" : [
                     {"id" : "1","name" : "bantul" }
                   ]
           }
         ] 
        }
```

how to remove and update state with id='1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**REMOVE**

To remove the documents that match a deletion criteria, call the `remove()` method with the `<query>` parameter.

```
db.foo.remove({'province.state.id': '1'})
```

---

**Example**

First, insert data `Yogyakarta - Bantul`

```
db.foo.insert({a:'1', province: [{id:'1',name:'Yogyakarta',state:[{id:'1',name:'bantul'}]}] })
```

Insert data `Jakarta - Jakarta Selatan`

```
db.foo.insert({a:'1', province: [{id:'2',name:'Jakarta',state:[{id:'2',name:'Jakarta Selatan'}]}] })
```

Now, you have two documents

```
db.foo.find();
```

Result

```
[ 
  {   "a" : "1",   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "527b54c6cc937439340367f9"   },   "province" : [   {   "name" : "Yogyakarta",   "id" : "1",   "state" : [   {   "name" : "bantul",   "id" : "1"   } ]   } ]   },
  {   "a" : "1",   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "527b54d3cc937439340367fa"   },   "province" : [   {   "name" : "Jakarta",   "id" : "2",   "state" : [   {   "name" : "Jakarta Selatan",   "id" : "2"   } ]   } ]   }
]
```

Now, delete document where the subdocument `province` contains a field `state` whose value `1`.

```
db.foo.remove({'province.state.id': '1'})
```

Check

```
db.foo.find();
```

Now, you have one document

```
[ 
  {   "a" : "1",   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "527b54d3cc937439340367fa"   },   "province" : [   {   "name" : "Jakarta",   "id" : "2",   "state" : [   {   "name" : "Jakarta Selatan",   "id" : "2"   } ]   } ]   }
]
```

---

**UPDATE**

By default, the `update()` method updates a single document. If the multi option is set to `true`, the method updates all documents that match the query criteria.

```
db.foo.update({'province.state.id': '2'}, { $set: {'a': '2'} })
```

Check

```
db.foo.find();
```

Result

```
[ 
  {   "a" : "2",   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "527b54d3cc937439340367fa"   },   "province" : [   {   "name" : "Jakarta",   "id" : "2",   "state" : [   {   "name" : "Jakarta Selatan",   "id" : "2"   } ]   } ]   }
]
```